# JOOQ: extract value from Field

Tags: sequence, jooq

I have a table with PK and another column for other id. In some cases i need to insert record with equal values in both columns. For primary key values i'm using sequence, which gives a `Field<Long>` from `Sequences.MY_SEQ.nextval()`.

How can i extract value from a `Field<Long>` for guaranteed insert same ids in both columns? Using `Field<Long>` in insert clause generates 2 different ids in columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

`Long id = dsl.select(Sequences.MY_SEQ.nextval()).fetchOne().value1();`

Answer (score 1):

[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870658/521799) works, of course, but it will generate two round trips to the database. One for fetching the sequence value and another one for the insert. If that's not a problem, perfect. Otherwise, you can still do it in one single query using `INSERT .. SELECT`:

#### In SQL:

(using Oracle syntax. Your SQL syntax may vary...)

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, val)
SELECT t.id, t.id, 'abc'
FROM (
  SELECT my_seq.nextval AS id
  FROM dual
) t
```

#### With jOOQ

```java
Table<?> t = table(select(MY_SEQ.nextval().as("id"))).as("t");

dsl.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
   .columns(MY_TABLE.COL1, MY_TABLE.COL2, MY_TABLE.VAL)
   .select(
      select(t.field("id"), t.field("id"), val("abc"))
     .from(t))
   .execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas! Your solution allow to use single DB request, and it can be very useful for tables with high load (many inserts for example).